# System update using android management API

Tags: android-management-api, android-enterprise

I am looking into android enterprise system update policy https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#systemupdate
In the documentation, it is mentioned configurations things like automatic, windowed, etc. I want to know how the GMS device will pick the OTA system update package and process.

Answer (score 0):

AM API doesn't change which package is installed - that is determined by the OEM - but it can help to schedule when that OTA update is installed.

This `SystemUpdateType` is used to configure the schedule of your system updates.

AUTOMATIC - Install automatically as soon as an update is available.
WINDOWED -  Install automatically within a daily maintenance window. This also configures  Play apps to be updated within the window. This is strongly recommended for kiosk devices because this is the only way apps persistently pinned to the foreground can be updated by Play.
POSTPONE - Postpone automatic install up to a maximum of 30 days.

Note that OTA updates containing critical updates will be immediately downloaded and installed on the device even if you use the restriction POSTPONE and OEMs(manufacturers) will determine which updates are critical enough to bypass postponement policy.

If you want to postpone all OTA updates then you should  use [freeze period](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#freezeperiod).